# How to transfer multiple Data in one excel Workbook to another excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am hoping you could help me, make a Code for an Update button. I wanted to have a 1 workbook -Enter Data, that when I feel up the workbook, and click the update button, it will automatically update specific workbook, base on the workbook file. mentioned in the EnterData Workbook.

Eg. I want to Make EnterData with following Details.

ItemName:
Item Quantity:

Department: 3 Department per month
Sheet Name: Month
FileName: Depends on the ItemName

and once I click the update button, it will automatically update the specific file with the specific sheet name and department

Hope you could help me with this.

Comment: Plenty of examples on Stack Overflow already - try a quick search and use other people's existing questions and answers. Try some code out baed on examples you find and then show us your code and any errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you a good head start
I try to divide the work to be performed into simple, readable, and logical task.

- Use Constants for settings such as: Root Directories, Cell References, Column References
  I want to see this in the top of a module

  Public Const TartgetWorkBookName As String = "C:\Users\SomeFolder\Data.xlsm"
  Public Const TartgetWorkSheetName As String = "Sheet3"
  Public Const TartgetTopLeftCellAddress As String = "A1"

Versus this somewhere buried in code:

```
Dim TargetWorkBook As Workbook
Set TargetWorkBook = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\SomeFolder\Data.xlsm")
Set getTargetR1C1 = TargetWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")
```

Here is a rough draft of a basic pattern that I follow.  It is a working example.

```
Option Explicit

    Const TartgetWorkBookName As String = "C:\Users\SomeFolder\Data.xlsm"
    Const TartgetWorkSheetName As String = "Sheet3"
    Const TartgetTopLeftCellAddress As String = "A1"

    Dim TargetWorkBook As Workbook
    Set TargetWorkBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(TartgetWorkBookName)
    Set getTargetR1C1 = TargetWorkBook.Worksheets(TartgetWorkSheetName).Range(TartgetTopLeftCellAddress)

Sub PostRecord()
    Dim TargetR1C1 As Range, ItemName As String, Qty As Double, Department As String, Month_ As Integer
    Set TargetR1C1 = getTargetR1C1()

    'If your transfering a lot of data turn off
    Speedboost True
    '------Begin Loop
    '------For x = 2 to LastColumn
    '------Set Variables
    ItemName = "Dragon Sauce"
    Qty = 3
    Department = "Spicy Hot Stuff"
    Month_ = Month(Date)

    '------Post Varibles to taget
    UpdateRecord TargetR1C1, ItemName, Qty, Department, Month_

    'Next
    'Turn Everything back on
    Speedboost False
End Sub

Sub UpdateRecord(TargetR1C1 As Range, ItemName As String, Qty As Double, Department As String, Month_ As Integer)
    Dim c As Range
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    If Len(TargetR1C1.Offset(1)) Then
        x = TargetR1C1.End(xlDown).Row + 1
    Else
        x = TargetR1C1.Rows + 1
    End If
    y = TargetR1C1.Column

    Set c = TargetR1C1.Cells
    c(x, y) = ItemName
    c(x, y + 1) = Qty
    c(x, y + 2) = Department
    c(x, y + 3) = Month_

End Sub

Sub Speedboost(bSpeedUpMacros As Boolean)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = Not (bSpeedUpMacros)
        .EnableEvents = Not (bSpeedUpMacros)
        If bSpeedUpMacros Then
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Else
            .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Function getTargetR1C1() As Range
    Dim TargetWorkBook As Workbook
    Set TargetWorkBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(TartgetWorkBookName)
    Set getTargetR1C1 = TargetWorkBook.Worksheets(TartgetWorkSheetName).Range(TartgetTopLeftCellAddress)
End Function
```